# What are the various tools you should install in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [“Must have” Ubuntu packages](https://superuser.com/questions/4685/must-have-ubuntu-packages)
>   [“Must-Have” Linux Software](https://superuser.com/questions/1430/must-have-linux-software)

Hello,
  I am a rails, php, iPhone and android app developer. I was working on mac and windows and i moved to Ubuntu 10.04. Can u tell me what the general tools (regarding development or non development) are good to use in Ubuntu. Anything starting from music to development will be a help.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/4685/must-have-ubuntu-packages http://superuser.com/questions/52190/what-must-have-applications-do-i-need-for-ubuntu http://superuser.com/questions/1430/must-have-linux-software and http://superuser.com/questions/18730/must-have-text-terminal-applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to install the [SciTE](http://www.scintilla.org/SciTE.html) text editor, on both Linux and Windows. I find it much better then the default GUI text editors provided on both platforms and having the *same* editor on both platforms is a big productivity booster for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. *Editor* - vim, gvim if you know/want to know how to use it, or gedit which comes as default
2. *Development* - your compilers and interpreters of course

For most other things, there's pretty much already something installed, like *Rhytmbox* for music, *Firefox* for browsing, ...

Just have a look inside your application menu.